# Mapping static resources with version number in the path in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement the versioning when serving static resources with Spring MVC. I need to force the clients reload the resources when a new version of the application is deployed.

I've followed the spring official guide [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#cache-spel-context) and I cannot let it work with the mvc:resources, but it works in the JSP pages.

Here my configuration in springMVC-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/style-#{applicationProps['version']}/**" location="/style" />
...
<util:properties id="applicationProps" location="/WEB-INF/conf/application.properties"/>
```

and this is the part of the jsp that is working:

```
<spring:eval expression="@applicationProps['version']" var="applicationVersion"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style-${applicationVersion}/style-common.css">
```

and finally this is the page source in the browser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style-2.1-SNAPSHOT/style-common.css">
```

The problem is that this file is not mapped. When I click on it it says: resource not found...
Any idea how to proceed, debug, understand the issue?
Many thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out logs (enable INFO level if you haven't) to see if the `mapping` attribute of `mvc:resources` had correctly resolved the property etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/style-#{applicationProps['version']}/**" location="/style" />
```

By

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/style-#{applicationProps['version']}/**" location="/style-#{applicationProps['version']}/" />
```

Resource location attribute should be complete folder name.